# How would I best resolve this specific type of 'Unused local variable' warning?

Tags: solidity, solc, compilation

I have a function which returns multiple values.

In some places I use all of them, while in other places I use only some of them.

This short snippet can illustrate the problem:

```
contract A {
    uint256 x;
    uint256 y;
    uint256 z;
    uint256 w;
    function getVars() external constant returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return (x, y, z, w);
    }
}

contract B {
    A private a;

    function func1() external {
        var (x, y, z, w) = a.getVars();
        // Do something with all variables (x, y, z, w)
    }

    function func2() external {
        var (x, y, z, w) = a.getVars();
        // Do something with only some variables (x, y)
    }
}
```

For which, Solidity compiler gives me the following two warnings:

```
contracts/B.sol: Warning: Unused local variable.
        var (x, y, z, w) = a.getVars();
                   ^
contracts/B.sol: Warning: Unused local variable.
        var (x, y, z, w) = a.getVars();
                      ^
```

How would I best resolve this problem?

Of course, I could just "state" them explicitly, for example:

```
    function func2() external {
        var (x, y, z, w) = a.getVars();
        (w, z); // Avoid compilation warning
        // Do something with only some variables (x, y)
    }
```

But it seems like a pretty ugly solution.

Is there a compilation flag which I can apply **only for this specific file**?

Or ideally, is there something "nicer" that I could put in the code in order to revoke this warning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the variable that you are declaring, but don't use e.g.

```
var (x, y,, w) = a.getVars();
```

Comment: With the `var` keyword deprecated in Solidity 0.4.21 and onward, after replacing it with `uint256`, your solution no longer works. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Now that 'var' is deprecated, it looks like you can simply drop the var keyword and add the type within the brackets -

```
(uint256 x, uint256 y,, uint256 w) = a.getVars();
```

seems to work for me...